# Why are Postgis sequences not automatically updating in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm adding new features to a polygon datasets in QGIS. The data is held in PostGIS but when i have a look at the attribute table for the polygon the gid field is not automatically updating, the entry reads NULL

I'm editing under the postgres login which looking at the sequeneces in PGadmin says that

`ALTER TABLE parking_enforcement.restrictions_gid_seq OWNER TO postgres;`

Is there anything special that i need to be doing in Postgres?

Comment: use ALTER SEQUENCE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-altersequence.html incremental option

Comment: If there are a few NULL records in the column will this automatically add a unique value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your gid column is not a serial or doesn't have a default value set to nextval(..).

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL